# Hero section styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I am having trouble centering divs in a Hero section, specially the search bar. I have tried flexbox and other ways but it doesn't seem to look good in smaller screens, and I am not sure how to do it.

This hero is used on other sections of my app as well, but it is only looking bad for this particular section for which I am providing the css. I don't know if it might have to do with css colliding as It is used in sections which don't have a search bar for example.

This is my hero.js:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className={hero-mid2}>
        <img alt="HeroImg" src={props.heroImg} />
        <div className='hero-text'>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <p>{props.subHeading}</p>
          {props.showSearchBar && (
            <div className='search'>
              <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={event => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)} className={props.searchBtnClass} placeholder={props.searchBarText} />
              <button onClick={ handleSearchClick} className={props.searchBtnClass}>{props.searchBtnText}</button>
            </div>
          )}
          <a href={props.url} className={props.btnClass}> {props.buttonText} </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

And this is my hero.css:

```
.hero-mid2{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        background: black;
    }

    .hero-mid2 .hero-text{
        top: 30%;
    }

    .hero-mid2 .hero-text input{
        padding: 0.8rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 18rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .hero-mid2 img{
        filter: blur(5px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.hero-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.hero-text h1{
    font-size:3rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}

.hero-text p{
    padding: 0.5rem 0 2rem 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.hero-text button{
    padding: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 6rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(42, 95, 243);
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

[This is how it looks on 1000px screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnnsM.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `img` tag to show image. Instead use css property `background-image`. Please check this link for reference. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_background-image.
After that for centering `div` use `display: 'flex'; justify-content: 'center'; width: '100%;`. I hope it helps!

Comment: `img` tag should be used when the image has meaning to the user and `background-image` when the image is just a decoration. Also, w3schools is one of the worst pages to recommend. But the css properties are fine and should work

Comment: But the image is passed as a prop to the component, as the image varies depending on the section.

Comment: Try using inline styling that way you can pass the `prop` to the `backgroundImage` property.